# How can I determine existing e-mail forwardings?

Tags: exchange, outlook, forwarding

Of the users in our company's AD, those that have Outlook frequently use it to set up "out of office" notices and mail forwarding to colleagues. Sometimes they forget to set those up before leaving for their holidays, in which case I set it up using the Exchange Management Console.

I notice that forwardings defined with Outlook do not appear in the place where I create forwardings. This is in the user's *account properties > message transport > transport options* (I'm not sure if these are the exact terms as I'm using a German Exchange Server installation).

If the Outlook-defined forwardings do not appear here, where can I see which user has which forwardings and "out of office" notices set up right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this powershell command should help.  Note that this will only find server-side OOA, if they have client-side rules in their outlook there is no way for you to find them.

```
 Get-Mailbox | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.AutoReplyState –eq “scheduled” }
```

Edit: you can also change these using Set-AutoReplyConfiguration

Comment: I will try this out first thing Monday morning. Thanks!